# code splitting with react-loadable, react-router-dom and redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to implement react-loadable in my react+redux application using react-loadable library but I am not getting chunks of bundle when executing 'npm run build' under build

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow anoop! This question is too broad for us to help you, sadly. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Could you post your Webpack config?

Comment: Did you set up your Webpack for code splitting? https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/